# Android hashtable

Tags: java, android, hashtable

I want to parse Xml. In the xml there are multiple items, each item has a description, image and url amongst other things. I want to group all the items with the same description together and then have each item as a menu item. when clicking on the menu item it opens the list of all the items for that description.

Im thinking of using a `HashTable` with the key being the description and an `ArrayList`. Is there any other way?

Example

Something that I cannot figure out is this :

```
    Description    URL                 Image

    Cars        www.ford.com         www.ford.com/image.jpg
    Cars        www.vw.com           www.vw.com/image.jpg
    Boat        www.suzuki.com       www.suzuki.com/image.jpg
```

So Cars would be the key in the `Hashmap`, how do I have 2 `String`s? and then there would need to be 2 entries for Cars.

Comment: This solution looks right to me. Use HashMap, not Hashtable.

Comment: LinkedHashMap also has order in it so you can use it. Disregard my answer, I somehow missed the important part of your question.

Comment: Im thinking : ArrayList<HashMap(String, ArrayList<String>)>  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I support your solution.

I am thinking about encapsulate these three attributes as an object, in case that you don't care about the order, i refer using `HashTable` with the key of the description and values are `ArrayList` with the classes you have created which has the three attributes you described. With this solution, you can conveniently access all the objects you want.

Hope to help.